# Are JVM languages bound by the Java Memory Model or just the Java Programming Language?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

Is the memory model for Java a feature of the Java Programming Language or a feature of the JVM? Are JVM languages bound by the Java Memory Model or just The Java Programming Language?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: that was my first reaction as well, but the memory model is *only* really relevant when multiple threads are involved.

Comment: Memory Models are about defining how multiple threads interact with memory, this is very important in multi core and multiprocessor systems, and quite subtle, this is why it is filed under multi threading as well as java and jvm.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with concurrency in any way, as worded it is about source languages and the JVM implementation. Besides that concurrency doesn't matter anyway, see @T.J.Crowder comment about a large structure. It is more about multiple *references* which is irrelevant to concurrency again!

Comment: Why are people voting to close this question? I would appreciate an explanation as a comment?

Comment: @ams: Yeah, I'm not seeing how it qualifies as "not a real question." Seems like a real question to me.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: then maybe my understanding of the term "Java memory model" is flawed. I understand what was [initially developed as JSR-133](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=133). And that doesn't really handle GC (at least not primarily) but is *much more* about the interaction of multiple threads when handling shared memory (and happens-before relations). I wouldn't consider the GC behaviour to be part of the Java memory model.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: it's not the most reliable source, but [Wikipedia seems to agree with me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Memory_Model): "The Java memory model describes how **threads** in the Java programming language **interact through memory**." (emphasis mine).

Comment: this question is conflating two unrelated terms and concerns, memory handling which is runtime specific, and the language which is just syntax and nothing more.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Yes, we're using "memory model" differently, and your understanding of it [appears to be how it's used in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4). **Wow** would I not use "memory model" to describe that behavior, but that's what they did, so...

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Actually "memory model" appears to be the JLS term used for this, see my link above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strictly speaking the Java Memory Model [is part of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) as opposed to [the Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html). However, the JVM Spec depends heavily on the JLS to specify details of the operation and the Java Memory Model applies to every bytecode executed, no matter which language it was originally compiled from. Therefore all JVM languages are bound to it (or benefit from it, depending on how you look at it).

Comment: In theory, a language implementation could insert extra thread-realted code, or even split ostensibly single-threaded code across multiple threads.

Comment: The link you posted to the Java Language Specification as I understand it the Language spec is independent of the JVM spec or maybe I am wrong about that.

Comment: @ams: The [JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html) is separate from the language specification, but it relies on it heavily. Littered throughout the JVM spec you'll find citations in the form "JLS §x.y.z" because at the end of the day, the JVM was designed specifically to provide a runtime environment that enabled the Java programming language. We've moved beyond that, of course, but that was the basis... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I agree. These days the technical details of the JMM should probably be moved to the JVM spec, as they are *indeed* required from a conforming JVM (and not handled by the Java compiler `javac`). But back when JSR-133 was current, the distinction was not as rigorous as it should be today.

Answer (score 4):

The memory model applies across the JVM, regardless of the source language in which the bytecode was written. By the time it's bytecode, it's bytecode.

Comment: technically behavior of the memory model and garbage collection and the like is JVM implementation specific. They have tried to tighten up the specifications, but there is still some wiggle room for interpretations and different implementations of the garbage collection routines.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Right, but the same model applies across the entirety of a specific JVM, and it must match the behavior defined by the [two relevant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) [specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html) in a conforming VM.